# React - using React-Router LINK tag causes parent to re-render

Tags: hyperlink, reactjs, duplicates, components, render

React newbie here. I'm stumped. I have a main class, that has a Header area and a Body area. The Header area has navigation links to download different categories of JSON. On startup, a random post is inserted into the body:

```
var React = require('react');
var Header = require('./header');
var PostRandom = require('./post-random');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log("MAIN.render");
        return <div>
            <Header />
            {this.content()}

        </div>
    },
    content: function(){
        console.log("MAIN.content");
        if(this.props.children){
            return this.props.children
        }else{
            return <PostRandom />
        }
    }
});
```

Here's Header:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require ('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;
var categories = {
    cats: [{
        name: 'Writing',
        id: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Essays',
        id: 15
      },
      {
        name: 'Poetry',
        id: 23
      }
      ]
  };

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        console.log("HEADER.getInitialState")
        return {
            topics: categories.cats,
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log("HEADER.RENDER");
        return <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <IndexLink to="/" className = "navbar-brand">
                        Home
                    </IndexLink>
                    <ul className = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {this.renderTopics()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
    },
    renderTopics: function(){
        console.log("HEADER: renderTopics")
        return this.state.topics.slice(0,8).map(function(topic){
            return <li >
                <Link activeClassName="active" to={"topics/" + topic.id}>
                    {topic.name}
                </Link>
            </li>
        });
    }
});
```

When I click on any of the links in Header, via a Route, it loads Topic and passes it the correct topic ID. componentWillReceiveProps in Topic then makes a call to a store which downloads a list of posts for that topic. This all works fine. The Router is pretty simple:

```
<Route  path="/" component = {Main}>
     <Route path="topics/:id"  component = {Topic} />
</Route>
```

**THE PROBLEM**: For some reason beyond my conception, *Main is re-rendered every time I click on a Link in Header*. This causes Header to re-render, which makes Topic re-render, which results in a 2nd call to the Store. I don't get it. The console output looks like this:

```
MAIN.render
MAIN.content
HEADER.RENDER
HEADER: renderTopics
TOPIC: componentWillReceiveProps
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
MAIN.render
MAIN.content
HEADER.RENDER
HEADER: renderTopics
TOPIC: componentWillReceiveProps
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
STORE: triggerChange
TOPIC:onChange
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
STORE: triggerChange
TOPIC:onChange
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
```

Immediately after the initial render of Topic, Main calls render again! This results in the Topic getting loaded twice, and two calls to componentWillReceiveProps, thus two trips to the store. I end up downloading the JSON twice, and get two different random arrays of posts. I see an initial list of random posts, then it is replaced by the 2nd random list of posts. Ugh.

If I reload the page, staying in the same topic, Main is NOT called a second time - so it's something about clicking on the Link that causes the re-render. Here's the console output from a reload:

```
MAIN.render
MAIN.content
HEADER.getInitialState
HEADER.RENDER
HEADER: renderTopics
TOPIC: getInitialState
TOPIC: componentWillMount
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
58 STORE: triggerChange
TOPIC:onChange
TOPIC: render
TOPIC:renderPosts
```

Also interesting: if I change the Link tag to just go back to the main page - that is, not calling/rendering Topic at all - like so:

```
<Link activeClassName="active" to={"/"}>
```

Main still gets re-rendered, which re-renders Header! Console output:

```
MAIN.render
MAIN.content
HEADER.RENDER
HEADER: renderTopics
```

So it has nothing to do with what goes on in Topic, or calls to the Store - the Link tag, when clicked, makes its parent component re-render! I'm sure I must be doing something wrong - but what? Thanks for any insight/help you can offer!

Comment: I am getting the same problem, the parent's render method is called again and again when the inner Link is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Render shouldn't trigger side effects. If you find yourself trying to control when `render` is called, you're going down the wrong path.

Routes render when their path is matched, the only time it won't rerender is if you write a `shouldComponentUpdate` that returns false in conditions when it shouldn't rerender--but don't use that to solve your current problem.

Instead of fetching data in `componentWillReceiveProps`, it should happen in `componentWillMount`.

Comment: 1. I'm not trying to "control" when render is called - it just doesn't make sense that it gets called there at all.
2. I had to use componentWillReceiveProps because the component gets updated with new JSON when the user clicks on the topic links.

GOOD NEWS: I (inadvertently) (mostly) solved the problem by solving another problem - the elimination of "junk" urls. I added a history param to Router (to get rid of "junk" urls) and am no longer getting the double rendering! (Plus my urls look nice...)